# jQuery fade in on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is a bit trivial but I just picked up jQuery tonight to add a little somethin somethin to my practice website, BUT I just cant seem to get this little script I wrote to work.  Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p4").fadeTo("slow", 0.25);
    $("p4").mouseover(function(){$("p4").fadeTo("fast",1.00);});
    $("p4").mouseout(function(){$("p4").fadeTo("slow",0.25);});
    });


<div id="p4" align="left">
BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAHfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
</div>
```

I also have some CSS

Comment: it sounds as though the jQuery pack is not being loaded if it works in jsFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine your HTML looks like `<div id="p4"></div>`.

So, you need to use `$("#p4")` everywhere to find an `id`, instead of `$("p4")` (which is actually looking for `<p4></p4>`).

http://jsfiddle.net/84k7e/

Comment: i surrounded <p4> with <div>.  I assume thats the same thing

Comment: I see you kinda added your HTML. Like I said in my answer, all you should have to do is in your Javascript, change all instances of `$("p4")` to `$("#p4")`. You don't really have those `<code>` tags in your HTML, do you :S (just checking..)

Comment: no i dont lol.  I did change my p4 to #p4, still nothing...Do I need <p4> tags if i have the id in <div>?

Comment: this sucks man.  it works perfectly on jsfiddle but not on my webpage...i even added the css to jsfiddle

Comment: @TrevorMA: Are you sure that `jquery.js` is being loaded?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

Comment: @TrevorMA: And is `jquery.js` in the same folder as your "webpage"? You can try `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`, which will load jQuery from Google. If it *still* doesn't work, it means you have some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

When using jquery, you need to have libraries downloaded.  Since most people dont have them unless they do heavy webdesign you have to import it from a host such as Google or Microsoft...

Using this code solved the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Thank all for your guidance! I appreciate it!

Comment: Didn't notice this answer until after I posted that last comment of mine. Funny that we thought of the same thing!