# Drop down menu disappearing before I get to the links

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at the **tour** link in the menu on [this page](http://bethhaim.spin-demo.com/contact). When I hover over tour, it's supposed to show the menu and let me choose which of the sub menus I wish to click on but it's disappearing too fast.

Here's the code of the menu:

```
$('.menu > li > a').filter(function(){
    if( $(this).siblings('ul').length ){ return true; }
}).hover(function(){ 
    $(this).siblings('ul').fadeIn(150); },function(){ 
    $(this).siblings('ul').fadeOut(150); }
);
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: You should add the `hover` event handler to the `li` element, not to the `a`.

Comment: That would be the normal way to do it, yes. But I want  to only make the submenu appear when you hover accross the text, not the entire block. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as easy as this:

```
$('.menu > li').hover(
    function(){ 
        $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(150);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('ul').fadeOut(150);
    }
);
```

Or, for the retarded boss:

```
$('.menu > li > a').mouseenter(function(){ $(this).siblings('ul').fadeIn(150); });
$('.menu > li').mouseleave(function(){ $(this).children('ul').fadeOut(150); });
```

Comment: it had to be siblings and children instead of find. Nice job though, it works like supposed to now :D

Answer (score 1):

150 milliseconds is a quite short timeframe. Use a longer timeframe instead.

```
.hover(function(){ 
    $(this).siblings('ul').fadeIn(1500); },function(){ 
    $(this).siblings('ul').fadeOut(1500); }
);
```

You may also want to keep it faded in while hovering on the sub menu...
You need to change you selectors (reference the whole listitems instead of the link only).

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/E4EjZ/

```
// INIT
$('.menu > li > ul').hide();

$('.menu > li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').fadeIn(1500); },function(){
    $(this).find('ul').fadeOut(1500); }
);
```

Comment: The links still disappear if I hover away  from the `<a>` tag. I need it to stay if I'm hovering the `<ul>` of the sub menu

Comment: @imjp I added a sample for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.menu > li > a').filter(function(){
    if( $(this).siblings('ul').length ){ return true; }
}).mouseenter(function(){ 
    $(this).siblings('ul').fadeIn(150); }
).mouseleave(function(){ 
    $(this).siblings('ul').fadeOut(150); })
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because the mouseenter/leave is still based on the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using onhover, you could try fading in on mouse over and fading out on mouse out.  That might work better for your situation and give you more control over each separate event.  Check out the example posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131305/jquery-fade-in-on-mouseover).

Comment: That's wrong. He defines two handlers for hover (over, out). Check the jQuery API. -- http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Smamatti You're right, I changed my answer to remove the false statement but still get my point across.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your mouse pointer over the 'tour' link you'll see that it doesn't fade away. But when you move your mouse away from the a element it fades away, like it's supposed to.

If you use hover with the parent li element instead, it'll work for the whole container which includes both the 'tour' link and the sub menu you're fading in.